# Multiple matches of the same type in preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to use preg_match to return an array of every match for parenthesized subpattern.

I have this code:

```
    $input = '[one][two][three]';

    if ( preg_match('/(\[[a-z0-9]+\])+/i', $input, $matches) )
    {
        print_r($matches);
    }
```

This prints:

```
Array ( [0] => [one][two][three], [1] => [three] )
```

... only returning the full string and the last match.  I would like it to return:

```
Array ( [0] => [one][two][three], [1] => [one], [2] => [two], [3] => [three] )
```

Can this be done with preg_match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) with the `+` dropped.

```
$input = '[one][two][three]';

if (preg_match_all('/(\[[a-z0-9]+\])/i', $input, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [one]
            [1] => [two]
            [2] => [three]
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [one]
            [1] => [two]
            [2] => [three]
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = '[one][two][three]';

if ( preg_match_all('/(\[[a-z0-9]+\])+/iU', $input, $matches) )
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```